# UIWebView orientation change

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I want to launch a mobile website as an app on iPhone so I've use the UIWebView component.
I want my app to support orientation change,so I've written the following code but I'm not getting expected result. 
Please suggest me what changes to be made in order to fix the problem.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/BVdK31KY) is my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect solution for you question,
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html

Answer (score 1):

which version is your test device?
you should notice that

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` is deprecated in ios6

Comment: test device version of iOS is 5.1.1